# Passing argument to indexedDB callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, indexeddb

I am pretty new to JS and even newer to indexedDB.
My problem is that I need to refer to an object from within a callback function.
Because "req.onsuccess" is not called synchron, "this" does not refer to a Groupobject.
Thats why "this.units" and other variables are undefined.
A very dirty workaround would be a global variable but I am just not willing to do that.
Is there another way?
Maybe passing an argument to the callback?

```
function Group(owner, pos)
{
    this.name = "";
    this.units = [];
    //...
}
Group.prototype.addUnit = function(unit)
{
    let req = db.transaction(["units"]).objectStore("units").get(unit);
    req.onsuccess = function(event)
    {
        let dbUnit = event.target.result;
        if (dbUnit)
        {
            this.units.push(dbUnit);//TypeError: this.units is undefined
            if (this.name == "")
            {
                this.name = dbUnit.name;
            }
        }
    };
};
myGroup = new Group(new User(), [0,0]);
myGroup.addUnit("unitname");
```

Thanks for helping!

**EDIT**

Using "bind(this)" solved the problem.

```
Group.prototype.addUnit = function(unit)
{
    let req = db.transaction(["units"]).objectStore("units").get(unit);
    req.onsuccess = function(event)
    {
        let dbUnit = event.target.result;
        if (dbUnit)
        {
            this.units.push(dbUnit);//TypeError: this.units is undefined
            if (this.name == "")
            {
                this.name = dbUnit.name;
            }
        }
    };
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: So where's your onSucess? Let's try Bind, call, apply in JS http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/

Comment: That solved my problem. Thank you! Is there a way to accept this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So where's your onSucess? Let's try Bind, call, apply in JS.
http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/.